# Typescript React 17 Tailwind CSS 2.0 installation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, tailwind-css

I'm trying to install TailwindCSS 2.0 with the `create-react-app --template typescript` setup with but I keep running in errors.  I have followed the documentation on their website for react https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app, but I i'm getting the error `Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'` when i try to `npx tailwind init`.  I have also tried looking around to see how other people are doing it up but I also run into other issues, does anyone know a alternative way to setup tailwind?  Thanks!

Here is my `package.json`:

```
  "name": "tailwind-example-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^5.9.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.16",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.8",
    "@types/react": "^16.14.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.10",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "postcss": "^7.0.35",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.2.0-dev.20201205"
  }
}
```

Comment: `npm install @types/autoprefixer`

Comment: @Roj still receiving the error after installing

Comment: did you install tailwind? http://ryanlanciaux.com/blog/2020/01/02/tailwind-with-react/

Comment: Yes, I have followed their docs.

Comment: how about the link i just shared?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the package [autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer).

Read the doc:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app#install-tailwind-via-npm

There it says how to install autoprefixer.